# Como puedo dejar de actualizar grillas automáticamente, AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Hola estoy tratando de que cuando modifico mi formulario las grillas no se me actualice  hasta que apreté el botón modificar. 
Busque en la documentación de angular y vi este updateOn, pero me actualiza la grilla una ves que salgo de ella y no cuando apretó el boton. 
`data-ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }`
Alguna solucion/idea?

Answer (score 1):

Con ngModelOptions puedes usar `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"` para actualizar el valor cuando uses un `<form>`.

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
  <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
  <input id="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

O si no algo como esto:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = { name: '' };
    $scope.save = function() {
      console.log("Guardando usuario: ", $scope.user);
    }
  });
```

```html
<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="save()">
      <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
      <input id="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
      {{user}}
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

**Editada:** Se ejemplo usando `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"`

Comment: Si muestras un ejemplo funcionando de la primera opcion que recomendaste, te ganas 10 porque te lo ganas.